# Spring Boot Gradle - avoid lib-provided folder in war file

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot based application and I'm trying to switch over from Maven to Gradle. The application is supposed to build a war file, which is deployed to a web server (WildFly in our case).

Now, I have some libraries provided by the web server and thus using a "providedCompile" scope (For hibernate search and infinispan). Now, when used with Spring Boot plugin, the plugin is creating the war file with all the "providedCompile" libraries moved to a folder named "lib-provided".

How do I avoid this? On the same context, it is also adding the Spring Boot loader classes on to the war file. If possible, I need to avoid this too.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only ever going to deploy your application as a WAR file to an app server, then you don't need it to be turned into an executable archive. You can disable this repackaging in your `build.gradle` file:

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried this and tried to supply my actual main class and also demo.application either didnt work. Should bootRepackage be dependent on any other closure?

Comment: @FirstX Oops, sorry. I copied and pasted the wrong snippet. I've updated my answer.